# path of 2columns-left.phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to change div sequence in 2columns-left layout view, But didn't find the respective file in Magento2. As we have in page/2columns-left.phtml file in magento-1.

Please let me know the path of layout files in Magento-2

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 2, there is no phtml file for 1column, 2columns or 3columns. You can find the xml files for the same at below path:

> [document_root]/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/ folder

or

> [document_root]/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/ folder

Please let me know if you have anything unclear.